# Symbian Qt custom fonts

Tags: qt, fonts, symbian

I'm trying to load custom font in a Qt application for symbian device. Obviously font are loaded correctly in the desktop/simulator application.

But when I try to execute on device it simply doesn't load the custom fonts.

Using the class linked [here](http://juhaturunen.com/blog/2010/12/using-custom-fonts-on-qtsymbian/) I've been able to load font in symbian. I can see the font calling the methods loadedFonts, but when I try to list available fonts using QFontDatabase it only shows me the standard font and not the recently added one.

To let symbian load the file I copied it from resource to "temp" directory on the C drive.

Any help would be really appreciated.

SL3

Answer (score 1):

This was a known bug .There is an explanation at this [link](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-6611) and possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

did you copy the fonts on ~/.fonts or /usr/share/fonts
list your font database

```
QStringList fm = QFontDatabase().families();
for(auto a : fm)
    qDebug() << "Font family: " << a ;
```

They should be there.

Check if the system sees the fonts: fc-list